# Jersey @PathParam at instance level vs at method level

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

In a Jersey class, Which is more appropriate of the two:

1. On an instance variable

@PathParam("service-id")
private String serviceId;

2. On a method argument

public Response subscribe(@PathParam("service-id") String serviceId){}

I'm using first one only because `service-id` is required by almost all my methods. However, a colleague of mine had a comment over this approach that ultimately Jersey classes are based on servlets and servlets should not have stateful variables.

I read about this in the [JSR-311 java docs](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/index.html)

> Because injection occurs at object creation time, use of this
>   annotation on resource class fields and bean properties is only
>   supported for the default per-request resource class lifecycle.
>   Resource classes using other lifecycles should only use this
>   annotation on resource method parameters.

Since in a webapp, my Jersey class ***is***  going to follow per-request resource class lifecycle, I feel first approach is safe. Thoughts please :)

Comment: It's safe. Stateful, in this context, would mean state in a singleton, application shared instance. If you have resources configured for per-request, there's no state maintained outside the single use of the request instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *made safe* by virtue of only allowing this annotation in request-scope (so that every request gets its own bean/resource instance and there is no shared state).

I'd probably give each method the full set of parameters, though, even if it is a bit repetitive. Makes it easier to see at a glance what is going on. That's a code style issue, though, and people can have different opinions here.

Comment: I get the code style part, but now I can be sure that if at all I'm re-factoring my code, I'm doing it for the right reasons :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is only coding styles issues since this code has exactly the same result.
I also prefer to define it in the method, instead of defining it in the instance.

Whatever, once compiled, the result is the same! :)

Comment: "Whatever, once compiled, the result is the same! " just curious about this - same how? Arey they both treated as instance variables or local variables within method?